# List header - custom person or group field

Tags: custom-list, person, style.css

I have the below code which modifies the look of my table and it works very well however the columns which are custom made person/group fields are not showing the same font colour as the rest of the columns (black). I believe this might be because of the icon that appears before the name but the 'Modified by' column is fine.

Also does anyone know how to specify a border around the heading row?

[image]

Many Thanks

```
/* ---------- Table Rows ----------*/
/* Set background for every row */
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr {
    background: white;
}

/* Set border for every row */
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr td{
    border-top: 2px solid Black !important; /* !important needed over override         SharePoint inline style */        
    border-left: 1px solid lightblue!important;
    border-right: 1px solid lightblue!important;
}

/* Set background for every alternating row */
.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr.ms-alternating {
    background: #F0F8FF;
}

/* ---------- Table Header Row ----------*/
/* Remove background set in SharePoint's general data table style */
.ms-listviewtable tr.ms-viewheadertr {        
   background: transparent;
}

/* Modify background color */
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon, /* Input box and attachment icon */
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh, /* Text */
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2,
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2-nofilter,
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2-div,
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th /* Text */ {
    background: #A9A9A9;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Modify background color on hover */
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh:hover,
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh2:hover,
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th  {
    background-color: #778899;
    border-color: #273C51;
}

/* Modify font color */
.ms-viewheadertr a,
.ms-viewheadertr div {
    color: Black;
}


/* Modify font color on hover */
.ms-viewheadertr a:hover,
.ms-viewheadertr div:hover {
    color: white;
}
tr.ms-viewheadertr > th.ms-vh-icon:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I can't replicate column headers with those icons...is there custom code in your site?

Comment: Thanks Danny, I have added a screenshot if you are able to help?

Comment: No, still not enough, select the THEAD in F12 and show in a screenshot what HTML and CSS classes are used (since I can't replicate your screenshot)

Comment: Thanks, I've added another screenshot which is hopefully what you need

Comment: That is the documents HEAD, not the THEAD of the Table you are trying to change with CSS.. right click the column you want to change and do inspect-element

Comment: Sorry about that, i have added the screen shots now (hopefully right)

Comment: We're nearly there; open the 2 DIVs (and any children) in the top image TH,  That is the required screenshot

Comment: and make the right column show where the incorrect color is selected

Comment: is CPMO 3rd party software you are using?? I see that as a Fieldname.. typically not a notation the average user does.

Comment: Hi, it is just a custom field I added where people lookup the name of the user from the e-mail directory who should be assigned to the information in that row

Comment: You need to drill down into the HTML with the inspector to find which CSS rule sets the color, then counter that CSS rule with higher Specificity CSS, unless it is set with !important, then you could be out of luck

Comment: I can't replicate that icon in the header.. if you added a custom Field (which you did not create yourself) and it has this CPMO (internal) name.. I am inclided to say you are using 3rd party software

Comment: Hi Danny, I did create the field myself. I went to list settings > create column > called it 'CPMO Owner' and selected the column to be 'person or group' type

Comment: I can't replicate your View, I can't get icons in the header. ``[aria-label^='CPMO']{color:red}`` works fine for me

Comment: Hi Danny, I think the icon is because it shows the ststus for that person as in are they online/busy/out of office - it is working off the company chat system so maybe it is a third party thing as you mentioned. I've added the screenshots you asked for. I appreciate your help with this

Comment: Updated answer, this is as far as we can go

Answer (score 0):

### Your color question

I have to see a screenshot

I see you use `!important` , that means you are missing some **more important** CSS knowledge about CSS Specificity (around for over a decade):

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

[image]

Your color black is not applied because the `ms-vh` classname on the element itself overrules is.

Learn **CSS Specificity**:
https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

### Border around the header

since `thead` or `tr` can't have a border, you have to set all TH elements

```
.ms-listviewtable thead th{
    border-top:1px solid green;
    border-bottom:1px solid green;
}
.ms-listviewtable thead th:first-of-type{
    border-left:1px solid green;
}
.ms-listviewtable thead th:last-of-type{
    border-right:1px solid green;
}
```

More reading: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Comment: forgot to thank you for the heading code, it worked perfectly